# removing balls from a bucket

Tags: probability

In a bucket there are 3 red balls, 5 yellow balls, 2 green balls and one white ball. We remove 5 random balls from the bucket (without inserting them back), what is the probability that every color appears?

I think that the answer is $\ \ \frac{1}{11}*\frac{5}{10}*\frac{3}{9}*\frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{264}$

Is it correct?

Comment: What you have computed is the probability to get the white ball, then one yellow, then  one red, and finally one green, **in that order**. How can you adjust?

Comment: multiply by $5!$ maybe... @Thanassis

Comment: @lior it's slightly more involved, one of the colors has to be 'duplicated'  - you can get 2 reds, 1 yellow, 1 green, one white - is just one way of meeting the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you need for example, 2 reds, 1 yellow, 1 green 1 white - and so on with the other combinations where the 'extra' ball is one of the other colors (which can not be white, or there would be two whites chosen)

I think it is

$(\binom {3}{2} \binom {5}{1} \binom {2}{1} \binom {1}{1} + \binom {3}{1} \binom {5}{2} \binom {2}{1} \binom {1}{1} + \binom {3}{1} \binom {5}{1} \binom {2}{2} \binom {1}{1}) / \binom {11} {5} = 5 / 22$

I've got this result with experimental simulation